# Setting up react-redux with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to get my head around implementing `redux` into `react`. I understand the basics as to how `stores`, `reducers` and `actions` work. I am now trying to set up `react-redux`. I know there is quite  a bit of documentation online, and as well as it is explained, it is slightly tricky to follow.

Here is what I have tried below, but it is not working. Can anyone spot some obvious mistake. I think I am close, but have made some small errors. Nothing is rendering on the screen at all.

Here is a [jsiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypnnkjk7/44/).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function counter(state = 0, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
var store = createStore(counter);

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    count: store.getState()
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
    increaseCounter() {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'INCREMENT'
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>   
                <h1>{this.props.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.increaseCounter.bind(this)}>Click here </button>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
    , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: After looking into the code above. I found that `this.increaseCount.bind(this)` which should be `this.increaseCounter.bind(this)`. Please check into the code once.

Comment: @duwalanise updated this part of the question. Thanks!

Comment: does that works now or still the same problem..

Comment: It looks fine. Any errors in the console? Do you have an element by the id of "app" available on the page?

Comment: @Chris no error, just not rendering. Do I need to use a `provider` also to get it to work with `react-redux`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to connect our component with the redux-store to use store which is done by connecting the component with the require part of store object in this case store itself.

```
const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    users: store
  };
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

if we had store object like

```
{
   counter: 0,
   ...   
 }
```

we can get counter as

```
const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    counter: store.counter
  };
}
```

And the next thing is we have to provide the store object to the connected component. This is done be wrapping the component with Provider.

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <ConnectedApp />
</Provider>
```

Note : After wrapping the component with Provider. We can access store object not only inside the direct Component but also all its decendent component. But it should be connected as the above one.

I have updated your fiddle. Please take a look [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypnnkjk7/45/)

```
const { Component } = React;
const { combineReducers } = Redux;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;

function counter(state = 0, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

var store = createStore(counter);

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    users: store
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {

    increaseCounter() {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'INCREMENT'
        })
    }

    render() {
  console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>   
                <h1>{this.props.users}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.increaseCounter.bind(this)}>Click here</button>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: in case someone comes along with the same issue do you want to explain what you changed?

Comment: So the first thing i did was connected the app component 
`const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);` 
and wrapped the connected component with provider passing the store.
`<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>`

Comment: best to explain in the question so the next person will see it

Answer (score 1):

You importing your Component without connect

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
    , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Try this

```
ReactDOM.render(
 connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
 , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Or this

```
  const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
  ReactDOM.render(
   <ConnectedApp/>,
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: it still doesn't show the value of the redux `state` - see js fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/ypnnkjk7/44/

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<button/>` closing element, instead of a `</button>`, which would prevent anything from rendering.

**EDIT** The question has changed, so hence an edit:

```
const { Component } = React;
const { combineReducers } = Redux;
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;

function counter(state = 0, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
var store = createStore(counter);

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
console.log(state)
  return {
    count: state
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
    increaseCounter() {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'INCREMENT'
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>   
                <h1>{this.props.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.increaseCounter.bind(this)}>Click here </button>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}
const CApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}><CApp /></Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

There were a few things wrong with the original code:

- missing the Provider wrapper
- not using the connected component

Comment: thanks chris. well spotted. However, the redux part is still not working. Can you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Can you set it up in a codepen or jsbin? it will make it easier to debug